# How to update/change HTML content with JavaScript and prevent the page from refreshing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm a newbie to scripting.  I want to update HTML content with JavaScript, but as you can see
the web page keeps refreshing.

How can I prevent the page from refreshing?

**Javascript:**

```
function showResult(form) {
var coba=form.willbeshown.value;
var coba2=coba+2;
document.getElementById("showresulthere").innerHTML=coba2;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="willbeshown" value="">
<button onclick="showResult(this.form)">Ganti1</button>
</form>
<p id="showresulthere">Result will be shown here</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t use a form at all. You are not submitting any form data to a server. To process data in the browser, you don’t need a form. Using a form just complicates things (though such issues could be fixed by using `type=button` in the `button` element, to prevent it from acting as a submit button).

```
<input type="text" id="willbeshown" value="">
<button onclick=
  "showResult(document.getElementById('willbeshown'))">Ganti1</button>
<p id="showresulthere">Result will be shown here</p>
<script>
function showResult(elem) {
  document.getElementById("showresulthere").innerHTML = Number(elem.value) + 2;
}
</script>
```

I have used conversion to numeric, `Number()`, as I suppose you want to add 2 to the field value numerically, e.g. 42 + 2 making 44 and not as a string, 42 + 2 making 422 (which is what happens by default if you just use an input element’s value and add something to it.

Comment: Helpful explanation, and works perfectly, many thanks! :)
but what does 'elem' mean anyway?

Comment: In the code, “elem” is just a formal argument in the function and could be replaced by any free identifier. But the role of the argument is that it is an object representing an HTML element. The corresponding actual argument in the function call uses a method that gets an element by its `id` value.

Answer (score 2):

Your button should be

```
<button onclick="showResult(this.form); return false;">Ganti1</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showResult(form) {
  var coba=form.willbeshown.value;
  var coba2=coba+2;
  document.getElementById("showresulthere").innerHTML=coba2;
  return false; // prevent form submission with page load
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/187/)**

Answer (score 0):

The others will explain how you should use jQuery, but this would explain why it didn't work in your original code.

The `<button>` tag submits the form, so you have to add this inside your form tag to prevent form submission:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

Btw, even without giving your form an explicit action, it uses the current page to submit; it's easy to think that it will not do anything without an action.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a `<button />` without defining its type it will work like a `submit` button. Just add `type="button"` to your button markup and the form won't be submitted.

```
<button type="button" onclick="showResult(this.form)">Ganti1</button>
```

With this change you won't need any `return false` or `.preventDefault()` "workarounds"