# How to replace HTML with another chunk of HTML Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I'm attempting to make a page where I click on a button and the HTML code of the div next to it changes. Essentially, I want to be able to click a link and my code inside the div changes.

Here are the two different HTML codes:

Number One: (id = contentPOP)

```
<div id="contentPOP">
            <h3>Hit like a girl entry, "Little Black Dress" by One Direction</h3>
            <iframe width="500" height="300"    
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QW6naMc6TWk?list=UUHe-Lb7DWhwT5S7Vzn7abxA"
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>   </iframe>
                <br>
            <h3>Remembering Steve Jobs</h3>
             <iframe width="500" height="300"
                     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q7oyy0FjhAY?list=UUHe-Lb7DWhwT5S7Vzn7abxA"    
                     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

Number Two (id = "contentNEW")

```
<div id="contentNEW">
          <h3>Slow Motion War!</h3>
            <iframe width="500" height="300" 
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y2996S-8oEU?list=UUHe-Lb7DWhwT5S7Vzn7abxA" 
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <br>
            <h3>1 Year Aniversary of Teddy Bear Productions!</h3>
            <iframe width="500" height="300" 
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7Tim_K74ua8?list=UUHe-Lb7DWhwT5S7Vzn7abxA" 
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
```

[Here is an example of all the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azOdMq)

NOTE: I have no idea how to do this, so a detailed explanation would be very helpful. Also, I want to be able to do this with only JS, no JQuery

Comment: Could you show us the JavaScript you have so far please?

Comment: nice effort, have you tried to google something like "javascript replace html" ?

Comment: I dont have any JS right now, as I have no idea how to attempt this. I've been searching w3schools for some help, with no avail

Comment: How about at least searching on SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961697/how-to-update-change-html-content-with-javascript-and-prevent-the-page-from-refr

Comment: I have, the problem is, I want to put in a large amount of HTML. (Like i click on a link which calls a JS function which changes the HTML Code)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tedugihate/1/

Comment: is it not possible to replace large chunks of HTML? B/C that is what all of u guys are implying, as you are only showing me how to replace small bits of text

Comment: ok, you guys could have just told me that instead of downvoting me. Thanks anyway, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen, this is done very easily. Wrap both chunks of code inside of their own divs and give them unique IDs so that you can target them in the jquery. The inittialy hidden one, will have a `display:hidden` class attached to it and then you can use toggle to switch . Easy!

[HERE IS AN EXAMPLE!!!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJbdrV)

Good luck!

HTML

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="hidden">This is a second paragraph.</p>
<button>Toggle </button>
```

CSS

```
  .hidden{
     display:none;
  }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
   $("p").toggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: yours is the only one that wrks, so i'll accept it. However, I dont really understand JQuery so no upvote

Answer (score 1):

First, **uncomment** the following so it exists on the page:

```
<!--THE BELOW CODE SHOULD REPLACE THE ABOVE CODE
<div id="contentNEW">
  ...
</div>
-->
```

And instead hide it with CSS:

```
#contentNEW { display: none; }
```

Then add the following to your `newVids()` function:

```
function newVids() {
  // target the div you want to change
  var div = document.getElementById('contentPOP');
  // replace its innerHTML with the innerHTML of the hidden div
  div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('contentNEW').innerHTML;
}
```

This is really a poor way to go about what you're trying to do. You shouldn't think about toggling the visibility of each div, instead of replacing one with the other.